# Proof for positive definiteness of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, eigenfunctions

Let A be N$\times$ N symmetric matrix having all real entries. The entries of A be $a_{ij}$ where $i,j \in {1,2,..N}$ and $a_{ij}$ is given by 
$$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
 f(n)=\dfrac{n^\zeta-2(n-1)^\zeta+(n-2)^\zeta}{2}, & \text{for } i\neq j,  \text{$n= |i-j+1|$} \\
 1, & \text{for } i=j \\
 \end{cases}$$ 
Where $1\leq \zeta \leq 2$. Prove that A is a positive definite matrix.

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question, lest it would be closed. See: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but it sticks out to me that the numerator of $f(n)$ is the difference of differences. That is, $2f(n)=(n^\zeta-(n-1)^\zeta)-((n-1)^\zeta-(n-2)^\zeta).$

Comment: Also, it is sufficient to show that the determinant is positive for every $N,$ because a matrix is positive definite if and only if its leading principal minors are all positive.